# Can't add rows to DB using Python's MYSQLdb module

Tags: python, mysql

For the life of me I can't figure out why the below module won't add new rows to my DB. I can add them using the command line interface. I can also add them by using other means (ie. writing commands to a script file and using `os.system('...')`, but if I use `cursor.execute()`, no rows are added (even though the table is created). Here is a minimal script for your viewing pleasure. Note that I am getting no errors or warnings when I run this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb

if __name__ == '__main__':
   db = MySQLdb.connect ( host="localhost", user="user", passwd="passwd", db="db" )
   cursor = db.cursor()

   cursor.execute ( 
   """
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS god_i_really_hate_this_stupid_library
      (
         id            INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
         username      VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
         PRIMARY KEY(id)
      ) engine=innodb;
   """
   )

   cursor.execute ( 
   """
      INSERT INTO god_i_really_hate_this_stupid_library
      ( username )
      VALUES
      ( 'Booberry' );
   """
   )

   cursor.close()
```

Comment: have you tried db.commit() before cursor.close()?

Comment: @PaoloBergantino no I have not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call `commit` on your connection, otherwise all the changes made will be rolled back automatically.

Comment: I knew it was something trivial like that. Let me give it a quick try. Do I have to riddle my code `commits`, or just one at the end?

Comment: You have to call `commit` every time you want some change commited to the database. If you want every change commited automatically, the you can execute [`SET autocommit = 1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html) or use [this](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/private/_mysql.connection-class.html#autocommit).

Comment: *"all the changes made will be rolled back"* Not **all** the changes will be rolled back. The rollback will be up to last commit (and because some statements, especially DDL like `CREATE TABLE` are [implicitedly committed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html) and cannot be rolled back, anything before such a statement will not be rolled back, too.)

Answer (score 2):

From the [FAQ](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away) of MySQLdb:

> Starting with 1.2.0, MySQLdb disables autocommit by default, as required by the DB-API standard (PEP-249). If you are using InnoDB tables or some other type of transactional table type, you'll need to do connection.commit() before closing the connection, or else none of your changes will be written to the database.
>
> Conversely, you can also use connection.rollback() to throw away any changes you've made since the last commit.
>
> Important note: Some SQL statements -- specifically DDL statements like CREATE TABLE -- are non-transactional, so they can't be rolled back, and they cause pending transactions to commit.

You can call `db.autocommit(True)` to turn autocommit on for the connection or just call `db.commit()` manually whenever you deem it necessary.